# docker error vue exited with code 0 in windows machine

Tags: node.js, windows, docker, vue.js, npm

Docker compose vue is erroring out with exited with code 0, Is this error specific to windows machine?  Exited after "DONE  Build complete. The dist directory is ready to be deployed."

```
vue-1    |  WARNING  Compiled with 9 warnings9:45:43 PM
vue-1    |
vue-1    |  warning
vue-1    |
vue-1    | chunk chunk-025a0295 [mini-css-extract-plugin]
vue-1    | Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
vue-1    |  * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--9-oneOf-3-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-3-3!./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VSelect/VSelect.sass
vue-1    | despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
vue-1    |  * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--9-oneOf-3-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-3-3!./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VSubheader/VSubheader.sass
vue-1    |    - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s) ,
vue-1    |    - while fulfilling desired order of chunk group(s) , , , ,
vue-1    |
vue-1    |  warning
vue-1    |
vue-1    | chunk chunk-025a0295 [mini-css-extract-plugin]
vue-1    | Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
vue-1    |  * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--9-oneOf-3-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-3-3!./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VCheckbox/VSimpleCheckbox.sass
vue-1    | despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
vue-1    |  * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--9-oneOf-3-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-3-3!./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VSubheader/VSubheader.sass
vue-1    |    - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s) ,

---------------
-----------------


vue-1    |   dist/css/chunk-0339625b.ed49607c.css    25.49 KiB         2.65 KiB
1    |   dist/css/chunk-3445e30c.b5dcdad7.css    20.48 KiB         3.19 KiB
vue-1    |   dist/css/chunk-de745950.5cc82d43.css    13.62 KiB         1.78 KiB
vue-1    |   dist/css/chunk-09e31ac6.3acb1388.css    11.74 KiB         1.50 KiB
vue-1    |   dist/css/chunk-7ae38439.298a0239.css    11.71 KiB         1.47 KiB
vue-1    |   dist/css/chunk-bb90ddf0.85e964b6.css    11.65 KiB         1.43 KiB
vue-1    |   dist/css/chunk-967217fe.66ca51dd.css    9.67 KiB          1.61 KiB
vue-1    |   dist/css/chunk-025a0295.c3d1fc37.css    8.58 KiB          1.83 KiB
vue-1    |   dist/css/chunk-e09232e4.dcd5d3bb.css    3.04 KiB          0.71 KiB
vue-1    |   dist/css/chunk-8be22344.f3fcf7ba.css    1.30 KiB          0.53 KiB
vue-1    |   dist/css/chunk-c8721f60.49830f27.css    0.83 KiB          0.30 KiB
vue-1    |
vue-1    |   Images and other types of assets omitted.
vue-1    |
vue-1    |  DONE  Build complete. The dist directory is ready to be deployed.
vue-1    |  INFO  Check out deployment instructions at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html
vue-1    |
vue-1 exited with code 0
```

I'm trying "docker compose up" for do vue service up.
Vue Dockerfile file in included here.

```
FROM node:13.8.0-alpine3.11

ARG PROXY_SERVER
ENV http_proxy=${PROXY_SERVER}
ENV https_proxy=${PROXY_SERVER}

RUN mkdir /app
RUN mkdir /app/vue
RUN mkdir /app/vue/dist
RUN mkdir /app/vue/serve
WORKDIR /app/vue

COPY vue/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npx browserslist@latest --update-db
COPY vue/. .

ENV http_proxy=
ENV https_proxy=

COPY start.sh /start.sh

EXPOSE 8080
```

Including vue start.sh file.

```
npm run build
rm -rf /app/vue/serve/*
mv /app/vue/dist/* /app/vue/serve

if [ "$DEBUG" = "TRUE" ]
    then npm run --silent serve 2>/dev/null
fi
```

docker-compose.yml is included here

```
  vue:
    build:
      context: ./node/
      args:
        PROXY_SERVER: $PROXY_SERVER
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - ./node/vue/public:/app/vue/public
      - ./node/vue/src:/app/vue/src
      - ./node/vue/vue.config.js:/app/vue/vue.config.js
      - ./node/vue/package.json:/app/vue/package.json
      - ./node/vue/package-lock.json:/app/vue/package-lock.json
      - public-content:/app/vue/serve
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:8080:8080
    command: sh /start.sh
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's the expected result? If you want to deploy a Vue application, building the application should happen in docker build not on docker run. The container will exit as soon as the process within it is finished, so if the build process is finished the container stops, that's expected behavior.

Comment: I'm trying to deploy vue application but it exited after build.

Comment: Can you please provide the Dockerfile used to build the container?

Comment: Included with my question

Comment: The content of the `start.sh` script would be quite important as well to see what is executed when the container starts up. Can you also add this, please?

Comment: Included with question

Comment: The Dockerfile doesn't seem to have a `CMD`; did this get left out copying it into the question?  The `start.sh` script you added seems to exit unless an environment variable `$DEBUG=TRUE` is set; is this provided somewhere like the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: Both  start.sh and docker-compose.yml included.

Comment: As @DavidMaze mentioned, do you set `$DEBUG=TRUE` for example in your `.env` file?

Comment: Debug was False in .env, changed that as true and retrying now.

Comment: Worked finally. Thank you so much both of you